# Get global variable in class

Tags: javascript

I created a JavaScript class, and I would like to call a method inside every second, here is my code:

```
var MyClass = Base.extend({
    myMethod: function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var mc = new MyClass();
            mc.myMethod();
        }, 1000);
    }
});
var myGlobalClass = new MyClass();

myGlobalClass.myMethod();
```

Actually this code works, but I need to do a `new MyClass()` every time. I would had liked using `myGlobalClass`.

Is this possible ?

Just a precision `this.myMethod()` can't work in this case, if you thought of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reffer to the value `myGlobalClass` then you can just do so directly from the function

```
setTimeout(function(){
  myGlobalClass.myMethod();
}, 1000);
```

This works because Javascript doesn't just look for locals defined in the current scope when resolving names.  It looks at all of the parent scopes as well to resolve them.  In this case `myGlobalClass` is defined in the global scope.  Name resolution begins in the `setTimeout` function callback and it won't find it in the function, it will then search `myMethod: function() {` and won't find it there, it will then look in the global scope and discover `myGlobalClass`.  It will resolve the name to this value

Comment: first time i've ever heard an anonymous function in javascript called a lambda. interesting thought.

Comment: Oh... I did that id didn't work I thought I needed to do something else, I tried again and this time it works... I'm a bit ashamed cause it's logic. Thanks for your reply (I'll accept it in 10min)

Comment: @jbabey i changed my answer to remove references to lambda to avoid confusion with the proposed lambda feature of the upcoming ECMA version

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `setTimeout` to call method recursively. You could use `setInterval`, which make your code more clear.

```
    var MyClass = Base.extend({
        myMethod: function() {
           //..
        }
    });
   var myGlobalClass = new MyClass();
   setInterval(myGlobalClass.myMethod, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat an action every second, have you thought about using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`? Then `myMethod` wouldn't have to initalize the timeout on every call.

You could just do this:

```
var MyClass = Base.extend({
    myMethod: function() {
        // do stuff here
    }
});

var myGlobalClass = new MyClass();

setInterval(myGlobalClass.myMethod, 1000);
```

Comment: Ok I never searched for the difference, here I don't need an absolute precision but thank you for making me search at least I know where my old time bugs came from when I did this kind of things ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have several instances, give the function a name and call it recursively.

```
myMethod: function myMethod() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        myMethod();
    }, 1000);
}
```

This is buggy on IE8-.

Comment: In my opinion, going with multiple instances is a bad idea in general. It's quite simple to fix so you only need one instance.

Comment: @Jon: But why is he then using `new` and all? If there is only one instance, I would just go with a plain object.

Comment: He has to create at least one instance to have a reference to the method. But once he has a reference, there is no need to make a new one. In fact, he doesn't even need one reference as @JaredPar's answer shows.

Comment: Interesting I didn't know we could do this, but the answer of +JaredPar did it